# Magento 2: Display list of specific categories on Home Page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, frontend, home

**I need to show 6 specific categories on my Magento home page**. I have the  category ids with me. I want to display both the category image and name of that specific category. I have created a `category.phtml` and have the following code in this file.

```
<?php 
  $categoryHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
  foreach($categoryHelper->getStoreCategories() as $category): 
?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
      <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
    </a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And called this phtml in cms home page as:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Theme::category.phtml"}}
```

But it is showing only the root categories. Please help.

Comment: have you all six category id?

Comment: yes.I have all category ids

Answer (score 2):

Better idea  create a custom module for this.

This module must have below files:

- **`app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\composer.json`**
- **`app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\registration.php`**
- **`app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\etc\module.xml`**
- **`app\code\[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Categories.php`**

On block class, you should create category collection filter  and filter that collection by your 6 category ids

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Block;
class Categories extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;
  protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $categoryIds = array(CatId1,CatId2,...CatId6);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in',$categoryIds));
        return $collection
    }
  }
```

Then use this new block instead of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`.

See  idea how use block class at
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-list-of-all-categories-store-categories/

Answer (score 1):

You can used following code to get category collections.

```
$objectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
    $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 

    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category->getId());
        $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl();
    }
```

Comment: Please help me to get category image.

Comment: I update my answer with logic for category update. And if it help you, please accept, so it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have category ids, then you can directly call that category using below code.

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_id);
print_r($category->getData('name'));    
?>

<img src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```

Comment: On printing $category, I got a huge array.My system got hang.Is it possible to get category name and image only from that array.

Comment: Please help me to get category image

Comment: Check my updated answer. It may help you.